# Get layout of the Bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

am still learning process. I have problem with Bootstrap table. This two colums (trucks and cars should be centered), idea is to have like on this image:

[image]

This Truck and cars need to be centered, so when I add more cars and trucks it should always be centered. Also, this empty row should be removed.

```html
   
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">Trucks / Cars</th>
         <th scope="col">Lorem 1</th>
         <th scope="col">Lorem 2</th>
         <th scope="col">Lorem 3</th>
         <th scope="col">Lorem 4</th>
         <th scope="col">Lorem 5</th>
         <th scope="col">Lorem 6</th>
         <th scope="col">Lorem 7</th>
         <th scope="col">Lorem 8</th>
         <th scope="col">Lorem 9</th>
         <th scope="col">Lorem 10</th>
         <th>Lorem 11</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Trucks</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="592">
         <th scope="row"></th>
         <td>Title 1</td>
         <td>Title 2.</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>MTitle 3</td>
         <td>title 5</td>
         <td>title</td>
         <td>some</td>
         <td>01.10.2020</td>
         <td>15.10.2020</td>
         <td>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="border-top: 2px solid #006171">
         <td>Cars</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="592">
         <th scope="row"></th>
         <td>Title 1</td>
         <td>Title 2.</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>MTitle 3</td>
         <td>title 5</td>
         <td>title</td>
         <td>some</td>
         <td>01.10.2020</td>
         <td>15.10.2020</td>
         <td>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I am still learning so any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `rowspan=2` in `th`
Try this:

```css
.table tbody th {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">Trucks / Cars</th>
         <th scope="col">Lorem 1</th>
         <th scope="col">Lorem 2</th>
         <th scope="col">Lorem 3</th>
         <th scope="col">Lorem 4</th>
         <th scope="col">Lorem 5</th>
         <th scope="col">Lorem 6</th>
         <th scope="col">Lorem 7</th>
         <th scope="col">Lorem 8</th>
         <th scope="col">Lorem 9</th>
         <th scope="col">Lorem 10</th>
         <th>Lorem 11</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>      
      <tr id="592">
         <th scope="row" rowspan="2" class="text-center">Trucks</th>
         <td>Title 1</td>
         <td>Title 2.</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>MTitle 3</td>
         <td>title 5</td>
         <td>title</td>
         <td>some</td>
         <td>01.10.2020</td>
         <td>15.10.2020</td>
         
         <td>
         </td>
      </tr>  
       <tr id="592">
         <td>Title 1</td>
         <td>Title 2.</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>MTitle 3</td>
         <td>title 5</td>
         <td>title</td>
         <td>some</td>
         <td>01.10.2020</td>
         <td>15.10.2020</td>
         
         <td>
         </td>
      </tr>      
      <tr id="592" style="border-top: 2px solid #006171">
         <th scope="row" rowspan="2" class="text-center">Cars</th>
         <td>Title 1</td>
         <td>Title 2.</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>MTitle 3</td>
         <td>title 5</td>
         <td>title</td>
         <td>some</td>
         <td>01.10.2020</td>
         <td>15.10.2020</td>
         <td>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="592">         
         <td>Title 1</td>
         <td>Title 2.</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>MTitle 3</td>
         <td>title 5</td>
         <td>title</td>
         <td>some</td>
         <td>01.10.2020</td>
         <td>15.10.2020</td>
         <td>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I can not add ned car or truck, see link of fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7oq8c10d/

Comment: please check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xobncfeu/

Comment: Thank youm much better, can we remove this empy cell? see image: https://i.ibb.co/Fxh2RCt/image.png

Comment: Yes, you can used `colspan` in td like fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xobncfeu/1/

Comment: Great, is it possible to have a layout like this, truck and cars in one row, see image: https://i.ibb.co/cx80HMM/final.png

Comment: yes, please add rowspan="2" in td... check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xobncfeu/2/

Comment: Thank you, now if I add more cars table is messed up: see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hkwcxaru/

Comment: you need to adjust rowspan as per your row like this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uytqk0zd/

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th scope="col"  style="text-align: center;">Trucks / Cars</th>
             <th scope="col">Lorem 1</th>
             <th scope="col">Lorem 2</th>
             <th scope="col">Lorem 3</th>
             <th scope="col">Lorem 4</th>
             <th scope="col">Lorem 5</th>
             <th scope="col">Lorem 6</th>
             <th scope="col">Lorem 7</th>
             <th scope="col">Lorem 8</th>
             <th scope="col">Lorem 9</th>
             <th scope="col">Lorem 10</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td  style="text-align: center;">Trucks</td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="592">
             <th scope="row"></th>
             <td>Title 1</td>
             <td>Title 2.</td>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>MTitle 3</td>
             <td>title 5</td>
             <td>title</td>
             <td>some</td>
             <td>01.10.2020</td>
             <td>15.10.2020</td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="border-top: 2px solid #006171">
             <td style="text-align: center;">Cars</td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="592">
             <th scope="row"></th>
             <td>Title 1</td>
             <td>Title 2.</td>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>MTitle 3</td>
             <td>title 5</td>
             <td>title</td>
             <td>some</td>
             <td>01.10.2020</td>
             <td>15.10.2020</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Centers the text and delets the last row.

Answer (score 0):

You can align data to center in td by adding class center or text-center:

```
<td class="center">Trucks</td>
```

Or

```
<td class="text-center">Trucks</td>
```